# Problema contando respuestas correctas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy desarrollando un programa para preguntarme palabras. Intento recopilar el número de respuestas correctas, pero el contador me da en todos los casos `0` o `1`.

Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Aquí el código:

```python
diccionario = {}

numeropalabras = int(input("¿Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?: "))

for i in range(numeropalabras):
    palabra = str(input("\nIngrese su palabra en español: "))
    traduccion = str(input("Ingrese la traducción al francés de {0}: ".format(palabra)))
    diccionario[palabra] = traduccion

for palabra, traduccion in diccionario.items():
    print('\nCuál es la traducción  "{0}"?'.format(palabra))
    respuesta = input("\nIngrese su respuesta en francés: ")

    contador = 0
    if respuesta == traduccion:
        print("Su respuesta es correcta.")
        contador = contador + 1
    else:
        print("Su respuesta es incorrecta.")

print(contador)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

saca `contador = 0` del `for`, decláralo al principio del código.

Answer (score 2):

como te indica @Jose Emanuel Rojas Rivas

**al hacer el bucle `for`, cada vez que ingresas borras en valor de `contador` y lo inicializas con 0**, luego en el `if` al `0` le sumas `1`, pero como es un bucle vuelve a ejecutarse hasta que la condición lo permita y es cuando la variable `contador` vuelve a ser `0`

```
contador = 0    
for palabra, traduccion in diccionario.items():
    print('\nCuál es la traducción  "{0}"?'.format(palabra))
    respuesta = input("\nIngrese su respuesta en francés: ")
    if respuesta == traduccion:
        print("Su respuesta es correcta.")
        contador = contador + 1
    else:
        print("Su respuesta es incorrecta.")
```